# Using jquery ajax load() to transfer multiple data fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML form that I am trying to convert to submitting using the Jquery load() function. I have it working for a single field, but I have spent hours trying to get it to work for multiple fields, including some checkboxes.

I have looked at many examples and there seems to be about three of four ways of approaching this:
    Jquery .load()
    jquery .ajax()
    jquery .submit()

and some others.  I am not sure what the merits of each approach is but the first example I was following used the .load(), so that is what I have persisted with. The overall object is to submit some search criterion and return the database search results.

What I have at present:

```
<code>
// react to click on Search Button
$("#SearchButt").click(function(e){

var Options = '\"'+$("#SearchText").val()+'\"' ;

var TitleChk =  $("#TitleChk").prop('checked');
if (TitleChk) Options += ', \"TitleChk\": \"1\"'; 

// load returned data into results element
$("#results").load("search.php", {'SearchText': Options});

 return false; //prevent going to href link
});
</code>
```

What I get is the second parameter appended to the first.

Is there a way to get each parameter sent as a separate POST item or do I have to pull it apart at the PHP end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem as if you're stumbling over the wrapper, let's go ahead and just use the raw `$.ajax()` and this will become more clear.

```
$("#SearchButt").click(function(e){
    var Options = {};
        Options.text = $('#SearchText').val();
        Options.title = $('#Titlechk').prop('checked')) ? 1: 0; //ternary with a default of 0

    $.ajax({
        url: 'search.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: Options
    }).done(function(data){
        $('#results').html(data); //inject the result container with the server response HTML.
    });
    return false;
});
```

Now in the server side, we know that the `$_POST` has been populated with 2 key value pairs, which are `text` and `title` respectively.

Comment: e.preventDefault() instead of return false; unless you want to stop the event bubble (propagation) as well.

Comment: Excellent - thank you.  What is the purpose of using the .load() approach?  It took me a few seconds to decode your username :-)

Comment: @DavidG `.load()` is just a wrapper, nothing more. Although it has a special purpose, it allows you to target a page and return only specific elements and their children by appending a selector to the request. However, for your case, it's not a requisite, and therefore this is a bit more transparent of an approach. :)